# List only rows related to another list using pluck()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

So, I have three tables: farms, crops and harvests. When I want to register a harvest on my web page, I use pluck to display a dropdown list for farms and another dropdown list for crops in the same view. The thing is, when I select a farm from the dropdown, I can still see and select crops related to other farms, and das not good. How can I list only crops related to the previously selected farm? My HarvestController looks like this:

```
public function create()
    {
        $farms = Farm::where('users_id', Auth::id())->with('alias')->pluck('alias', 'id');
        $crops = Crop::where('users_id', Auth::id())->pluck('id', 'id');
        return view('harvest.create')
        ->with('farms', $farms)
        ->with('crops', $crops);
    }
```

The relationships in models:

```
class Farm extends Model
{
   public function crops(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Crop');
    }
}

class Crop extends Model
{
   public function farm(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Farm');
    }

    public function harvest(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Harvest');
    }
}
```

And the view looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('farms_id', 'Farm') !!}
            {!! Form::select('farms_id', $farms, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('crops_id', 'Crop ID') !!}
            {!! Form::select('crops_id', $crops, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}
        </div>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated, constructive roasting too

Comment: what are the relations and where do you call relation based filtering?

Comment: @ab_in I've updated my question, thanks

Comment: if you dynamically want to change the second form select, based on your first select, use AJAX?

Comment: use a ajax request and implement your conditions like this.  `$crops = Crop::where('users_id', Auth::id())->where('farms_id', $farmId)->pluck('id', 'id');` will give crops for the selected farm_id